# spring cloud stream multi sink with dynamic destinations

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I need to use dynamic group names for RabbitMQ binder based Multisink (multiple sinks) app.
Seems like the
spring.cloud.stream.bindings..group property can't be set at runtime.

Any thoughts on how to go about it ?
SPB: 2.2.8.RELEASE ,
spring-cloud-dependencies: Hoxton.SR6 ,
spring-cloud-stream-dependencies: Horsham.SR6

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a property placeholder there...

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input-in-0.group=${group.prop:foo}
```

...and then set the property on the command line:

```
-Dgroup.prop=bar
```

Comment: Thanx Gary, group name is something like :

'sharding: alpha - beta@server - 0'.

Any idea how to escape this property value ?

Comment: According to the [sharding readme](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding) you consume from the pseudo queue name, not the individual shards. That looks like `alpha` in this case; you set the group to `alpha`, set `queueNameGroupOnly=true`, `bindQueue=false` and `declareExchange=false`. If you have shards on `>1` node, you will need a binder for each. According to the docs, you can only consume from local shards: `How does it work? The plugin will chose the queue from the shard with the least amount of consumers, provided the queue contents are local to the broker you are connected to.`